# Unable to Use Local Characters (e.g., "İ", "Ş") in Material-UI DataGrid Filter

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, localization

I'm using Material-UI to create a DataGrid in my React-based application. However, I'm encountering an issue when trying to filter data using Turkish characters (e.g., "İ", "Ş").

Specifically, when attempting to filter data that contains Turkish characters, using uppercase "İ" or "Ş" letters for filtering doesn't work as expected, and I'm unable to get the desired results. It seems that the filtering process is not sensitive to Turkish characters.

Answer (score -1):

To enable the use of local characters in the Material-UI DataGrid filter, you need to configure the filtering behavior for the DataGrid component.

One possible solution is to use the filterOptions prop of the DataGrid component and set the matchFrom property to "start". This will make the filter match from the beginning of the text, instead of using a case-insensitive search.

Here's an example of how to configure the DataGrid component to enable the use of local characters in the filter:

In this example, the name column contains data with local characters. By setting matchFrom: 'start' in the filterOptions, the filter will only match the local characters at the beginning of the text.

You can customize the filter behavior further by adjusting the operatorValue and value properties in the filterModel object.

Make sure to replace the columns and rows with your actual data.

```
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';

const columns = [
  { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 70 },
  { field: 'name', headerName: 'Name', width: 130 },
  // other columns...
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, name: 'İstanbul' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Şişli' },
  // other rows...
];

const MyDataGrid = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        filterModel={{
          items: [
            {
              columnField: 'name',
              operatorValue: 'contains',
              value: '', // specify the initial filter value here
            },
          ],
        }}
        filterOptions={{
          matchFrom: 'start',
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyDataGrid;
```

Comment: not working for me,can you check on local project?